# How to get length of a dynamic array in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Is there a function to determine length of a dynamic array in Delphi ?

Comment: This question is trivially answered by the simple act of reading the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays

Comment: ...or even doing a few seconds of trial and error in the IDE. After all, the name `length` isn't very far-fetched.

Comment: Also answered by the first 5 hits in a Google search for `"delphi array length"` (disclaimer: I only looked at the first 5 hits)

Comment: @David, Cosmin: Great! Now we've covered the three 'obvious' solutions!

Comment: Regardles all complaints, this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @gabr It's a perfectly valid question, well formed, and easily answered by reading the documentation. Perhaps the next time I have a simple OTL question I'll just send you an e-mail asking for the answer rather than reading the manual!  ;-)

Comment: @gabr: SO expects at least minimal effort be spent to solve the problem yourself before posting here. The first three comments reflect the very *minimum* effort that obviously wasn't put into research for a solution.

Comment: I am sorry if this question seemed too obvious. I knew about the Length function but I knew it was for strings, not also for dynamic arrays :)

Comment: I put in the first vote to Close, but after reading a number of Meta questions on this, I believe I was wrong: the question is valid, should stay, but the answer should link to the documentation in a very clear way. It's supposed to help search engines properly rank hits, as SO *is* a good reputable source of info, and the documentation... let's be honest, you'll only find it if you know what you're looking for.

Comment: @TheNextPotentialCloseVoter, before you vote to close this question as *not a real question*, please read what does this vote means before you blindly follow the crowd! This is a valid and clear question!

Comment: Googled "delphi array length" (in quotes) - got Cosmin Prund's comment above as the first hit. :)

Comment: Where are you reading about the existence of dynamic arrays that *didn't* also mention the Length function? Please tell us so that we know *not* to recommend that resource to others.

Comment: I was the first who voted down, because the question isn't useful. (Check the hover text on the down arrow). Didn't vote for closure, because it is a valid question.

Comment: I also voted to close, and would retract that vote if I could. The question is indeed well-phrased and written. I would (and did) downvote it for showing little or no effort to solve it before posting here, but should not have cast the close vote. Unfortunately, there's no way to undo it once it's cast. :-(

Comment: @TLama It's an extremely poor question that shows no research effort. The closure reason might not be a perfect fit, but it doesn't deserve to remain open.

Comment: Use the Length() function. See this code on how to use it: https://github.com/GodModeUser/DemoCode/tree/main/DataTypes%20-%20SizeOf

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`Length`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Length) function to get the length of your array:

```
var
  ArrayLength: Integer;
begin
  ArrayLength := Length(ArrayOfSomething);
  ...
end;
```

From the reference for this function (emphasized by me):

> In Delphi code, **Length returns** the number of characters actually
>   used in the string or **the number of elements in the array**.

Comment: Thank you. I knew about the Length function, but the manual said it works only for strings.

Comment: No, the manual doesn't say that at all: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Length